# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bookstore.entity.City

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have 3 tables named for **customer**,**city** and **district**. While **customer** table is connected with **city** and **district**, **city** and **district** are connected with each other.

When I save the customer information via `hibernate`, the error appears as shown below.

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bookstore.entity.City
```

I could use an EAGER and Cascade option for all these tables but nothing can solve the issue.

Here are the tables.

Customer Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER",catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
public class Customer implements Serializable{ 

...

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CITY")
private City city;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "DISTRICT")
private District district;

}
```

City Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITY",catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
public class City implements Serializable{

...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "districtCity",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<District> districts = new HashSet<District>();

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "city",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Customer customer;
}
```

District Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISTRICT", catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
public class District implements Serializable {

...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID")
private City districtCity;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "district")
private Customer customer;

}
```

Here is the create option for Customer

```
String customerName = request.getParameter("customer_name");
            String customerSurname = request.getParameter("customer_surname");
            String customerPhoneNumber = request.getParameter("customer_phoneNumber");
            int cityId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("city"));
            int districtId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("district"));
            String customerAddress = request.getParameter("customer_address");
            String customerZipcode = request.getParameter("customer_zipCode");

            Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
            newCustomer.setName(customerName);
            newCustomer.setSurname(customerSurname);
            newCustomer.setPhoneNumber(customerPhoneNumber);
            newCustomer.setAddress(customerAddress);
            newCustomer.setZipCode(customerZipcode);

            City city = cityService.getCityById(cityId);
            District district = districtService.getDistrictById(districtId);

            newCustomer.setCity(city);
            newCustomer.setDistrict(district);

            customerService.createBook(newCustomer);
```

Comment: Please provide also code where you are perform saving customer.

Comment: Tijkijiki I share the create option code for customer with you.